Did Pradyumna grow suddenly like Vyasa?
In both the Garga Samhita and the Śrīmad-Bhāgavatam, Pradyumna’s story highlights his divine nature as the son of Krishna and Rukmini and the reincarnation of Kamadeva (Cupid). A key aspect of his narrative is the fact that he "suddenly grew" into youthful maturity, distinguishing him from ordinary beings.

Taken from the fish's belly, and carefully protected by his wife, Pradyumna suddenly grew to become a young man. Then he understood what his enemy had done.
[25, 8 , Garga Samhitha]
After a short time, this son of Kṛṣṇa — Pradyumna — attained His full youth. He enchanted all women who gazed upon Him.
[9, 55, 10, Srimad Baghavatham]

This suggests that Pradyumna’s development was extraordinary and much faster than normal human growth. The phrase "a very short time" aligns with the Garga Samhita's depiction of "sudden growth".
I seek clarification on whether these texts should be understood as describing literal instantaneous growth or whether this is an interpretative tradition. Are there any other commentaries or texts that elaborate on the nature of Pradyumna’s development?

This is told for Lord Krsna as well in the Gaudiya texts. It is taken in a literal sense since the childhood as seen in the material world doesn't exist in the spiritual realms from which the personalities descend to Martyaloka. Hence, they don't go through the slow growth from childhood to young age like the manushyas do.
